# Batch "goto" or IF statement leads to a different block of code

Tags: batch-file, block, goto

Here is a short batch program I made to call other batch files. The code is as below.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:choice
cls
@call makeline
echo Choose an action from below:
@call makeline
echo.
echo 1. Disassemble a suspect malware.
echo 2. Image a disk drive.
echo 3. Generate MD5 hash of a file.
echo 4. View Report.
echo 5. Exit Malverse 1.2
echo.
@call makeline

set "ch=%gch1%"
goto :chCheck
:chPrompt
echo Select by typing in the number [1-5] and hit the RETURN key.
set /p "ch=[1-5]: "
:chCheck
if not defined ch goto :chPrompt
echo %ch%
pause

if %ch% == 1 (
set ch=
GOTO disasm
)

if %ch% == 2 (
set ch=
GOTO image
)

if %ch% == 3 (
set ch=
GOTO hash
)

if %ch% == 4 (
set ch=
GOTO view
)

:hash
@call makeline
@call hasher

:disasm
@call makeline
@call disassembler

:image
@call makeline
@call imager

:view
@call makeline
@call report

pause
endlocal
```

This program should be giving output, say, if I enter 1 as the option from the menu, it should call the disassembler file.

```
Option: 1
Disassembler 2.2.
```

However, instead of doing that, it keeps calling the report file which is supposed to only be called by the option of 4. After running another test using 3 as the option, this time, it called the hasher file but then again also calling the report file later on.

Test Case: 1 results

```
Option: 1
Report viewer opened.
```

Test Case: 3 results

```
Option: 3
Hasher begins here.
Report viewer opened.
```

Curious, I also checked the file names and it appeared to match exactly. I have checked some sites but to no avail. Also, I tried to sort of debug using @echo on at the top of the code but no error message was displayed. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I asked further around...external to this site and finally got the answer, thought I should share it here,

```
if %ch% == 4 (
set ch=
GOTO view
)
goto end

:disasm
@call makeline
@call disassembler
pause
goto end
```

I have to add

```
pause
goto end
```

in each of the function blocks and a `goto end` at the end of the final `if` block to make it work the way I want. Thanks for replies and views. Credits for the solution to Max Chu; a friend of mine.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter 1, it will `GOTO disasm`, but on reaching `:disasm` it will fall through to `:image` and then `:view` and hence call the report. Did you mean to include `GOTO choice` after each block?

Comment: Actually that would be the next enhancement. However, I also tried that to add     GOTO choice     it still simply didn't call the disassembler file as expected. By the way, I would want to know how is it that it fall to
    :disasm
How to solve it?